# SQL Server - Create text files from value stored in a row

Tags: sql-server

I have table which has one field (Information).

```
Information
===========
Hello World 1
This is testing message
How are  you
```

I want to create three text files (as number of rows are 3) which will have content based on value in rows.

So,

- File1.txt will have `Hello World 1`
- File2.txt will have `This is testing message`

How can we achieve this in SQL Server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:-

```
use master
go

declare @DSQL Nvarchar(max)
declare @counter int
declare @maxrows int
declare @filename Nvarchar(30)

select @counter=1, @maxrows = 0

create table t1 (
 sno int identity(1,1) not null,
 filename varchar(5),
 filecontent varchar(100)
)

insert into t1
select 'FN1', 'Hello'
UNION
select 'FN2', 'Good Morning'
UNION
select 'FN3', 'How are you?'
UNION
select 'FN14', 'Where are you?'

select @maxrows = count(*) from t1

--SELECT * FROM T1

while (@counter <= @maxrows)
begin
  select @filename = filename from t1
   where sno = @counter
select @DSQL = N'exec xp_cmdshell' + ' ''bcp "select filecontent from master.dbo.T1 where sno = ' + cast(@counter as nvarchar(10)) + '" queryout "d:\temp\' + @filename + '.txt" -T -c -S home-e93994b54f'''

print @dsql
exec sp_executesql @DSQL
   select @counter = @counter + 1
end

drop table t1
```

Comment: Im getting this error with bcp command - Error = [Microsoft][SQL Native Client]Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [53]. I have tired everything but it doesn't work, any suggestions

Comment: any other ways besides using bcp utility